# Sending a GET request through js while using Electron

Tags: javascript, flask, electron

I am trying to send a HTTP GET request to my local flask server but for some reason it doesn't send. I am trying to build a leaflet map application with Electron and want to send some GET requests from the Electron frontend to the flask backend.

Here is all the code that i am using.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/locate", methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"
```

```
function loadShiz(){    
    var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/locate';

    Http.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (Http.readyState == 4 && Http.status == 200)
            callback(Http.responseText);
    }

    Http.open("GET", url, true);
    Http.send;

    console.log("test 1")
}

loadShiz();
console.log("test 2");
```

request.js ^^^

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/map.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="request.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Electron map screenshot]

You can see that i get the two console.logs but the flask server never gets a request. Whats the deal?

I get the response 200 when i enter the url manually in the search bar of a browser.

Comment: Look in the devtools network tab.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/skN8Sjj here is the screenshot of the network tab, i dont know what im looking for.

Comment: Basically you need to track down the request to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/locate` and click on it to see what the issue is.

Comment: Looks like for some reason the request wasn't being sent. After i switched to fetch() i was able to see the request on the network tab. And after fiddling with CORS i was able to make it work finally.